# PowerShell .Count returns 1 on empty array

Tags: arrays, powershell, count

If I use .Count to check the number of items in an empty array, like this:

```
$theNames = @()
$theTotalNames = $theNames.Count
```

it finds nothing, and the numeric variable $theTotalNames is 0, as expected

But I have a situation where if I use .Count to check the contents of seemingly empty array, it is returning 1.

I'm populating the array with the results returned from the Invoke-RestMethod query like this:

```
$responseData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers
$theNames = @($responseData.PsObject.Properties["the_field"].value.field_name)
$theTotalNames = $theNames.Count
```

If the query returns nothing because there were no fields found, $theTotalNames somehow equals 1. If the query returns one or more items, $theTotalItems will correctly equal 1.. or higher

When I display the contents of $theNames array after the query that returned nothing, the array seems empty.

If I check what's in the array, like this:

```
 if ($theNames) {
     "The array contains something"
 }
 else {
     "The array contains nothing"
 }
```

the console always says the array contains nothing.

So, why does .Count think there's at lease one item in the array?

Comment: Show result of: `$null -eq $theNames[0]`

Comment: $null is returning True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) implies in a comment, **the array may not be *empty* but may have a *single element* that happens to be `$null`**; the `.Count` property reports the number of elements irrespective of the *value* of the elements:

```
@($null).Count # -> 1
```

Work around the problem as follows (assuming actual values are never the *empty string*):

```
$theTotalNames = if ($theNames) { $theNames.Count } else { 0 }
```

This relies on the fact that **a *single-element* array that contains a "falsy" value is regarded as `$False` in a Boolean context**.

---

#### Optional background information

In PowerShell, **`$null` is generally a "something" (the "null *scalar*")**, whereas **there is also a "null *collection*", which is closer to "nothing", namely the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton**, which is "returned" by commands that have *no output at all*.

The simplest way to produce it is to call an empty script block: `& {}`

Trying to wrap that in an array indeed yields an *empty* array:

```
@(& {}).Count  # -> 0
```

However, in **PSv3+** there is (at least?) **one context in which `$null` too is considered "nothing"**:

```
foreach ($el in $null) { "loop entered" }  # loop is NOT entered.
```

I presume that the rationale for this intentional inconsistency is that *uninitialized* variables default to `$null` and that entering the loop for uninitialized variables would be undesirable.
For more, see [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7049#issuecomment-399808799).

Comment: IMHO, it is not that historical. IIRC, before v3 `foreach` count `$null` as value and enter the loop.

Comment: @PetSerAl: You are correct, thanks. The behavior was introduced in v3. I've updated the answer and added a - speculative - rationale for this behavior. Do let us know if you know more about this. Similarly, tell us if you know of other scenarios where `$null` is "nothing".